# Using Tk with C

Tags: c, user-interface, tk-toolkit

I’m a C programmer with no desire to deal with C++ tool-kits, and I’m trying to build a simple graphical card game.  I’m programming under Linux, but I’d like to have the option of a Windows port.  From what I’ve read, my options are GTK+ and Tk.

I’m working through some GTK+ tutorials, and I’ll probably stick with that, but I don’t think I’m giving Tk a fair shot.  Trouble is, all the Tk documentation I can find is either for using Tk with {Tcl, Ruby, Perl, Python}, or for embedding a Tcl interpreter into the C program and using Tk that way.  Is there an easy(-ish) way to use Tk to build GUIs for a C program without digressing too much into Tcl?

Ideally, is there a tutorial (something along the lines of the [TkDocs Tk Tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html)) but using something like the [Tk C API](http://wiki.tcl.tk/17267)?

Comment: Three pointers to embedding Tcl into the program to build the GUI with Tk.  Good to know, but I was hoping for the plain-C equivalent of [C++/Tk](http://cpptk.sourceforge.net/).  Which may simply not exist.  Oh, well.

Comment: It's usually harder to do it that way; C is a language that's _superb_ for building low-level components of a system, but it's nice to use a higher-level language to piece the C components together with. (I prefer Tcl for that, but the other ones you listed work well too.) I feel C++/Tk to be a very strange hybrid beast, almost like a mythological monster. :-)

Comment: Yes there is no way to use TK from C only. It assumes a working TCL infrastructure (like strings, hashs etc.). If this is a problem for you are left with GTK (or Win32 API) - but it shouldn't.

Answer (score 9):

Here are some useful links:

[Combining C and tcl/tk](http://davesource.com/Fringe/Fringe/Computers/Languages/tcl_tk/tcl_C.html)
[An Overview of the Tk C Library][2]

Answer (score 7):

Here's a reference: http://www.hume.com/html85/indexes/tkc_api.html

Intro to combine C with Tk: [http://davesource.com/Fringe/.../tcl_tk/tcl_C.html](http://davesource.com/Fringe/Fringe/Computers/Languages/tcl_tk/tcl_C.html)